# React.JS disable variable substitution

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to show some string with {} in some block but reactJS think that my {some_data} is a variable and tried to replace it. How can i escape `{some_data}` or tell to react that it not a variable?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display some static data? What is your expected outcome and your variable is getting replaced with what actually? Please clarify your question further and add code snippets if possible.

Comment: Thank you! `curly braces` is what i forgot to add to my googling

Comment: @suppaGonzalo yes, it`s static data. I want to see raw string without variable substitution. I cant share the code because im not have it (i make content for existed system now).

Comment: Try writing `"{some_data}"` instead of `{some_data}`.

Answer (score 1):

To display curly braces {} as literal text in JSX within a React component, you can use double curly braces {{}}

Comment: You're slightly off here. To display {} as literal text in JSX, you should use {'{}'}, not {{}}. The latter is interpreted as an empty object in JavaScript inside JSX.